# Определение одного onClick для нескольких кнопок Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-on-click

уважаемые пользователи!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы в общем методе onClick при нажатии на кнопку считывалось, на какую кнопку было нажато, и далее текст кнопки считывается в textView? 
Т.е., нажатие на кнопку -> определение, какая кнопка нажата -> textView = button.Text (образно).

Видел, где считывают id, закидывают его в switch, далее в case прописывают действие для каждой кнопки. Мне же надо, чтобы программа сама определяла кнопку и текст на ней.

Comment: В onClick приходит View, это и будет нажатая кнопка. Кастуете это View к Button вытаскиваете текст и сеттите в textView. `textView.setText(((Button)v).getText());`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon спасибо большое)